# How to format the hour of a date using Intl API as numbers only with german locale ("de_*")

Tags: javascript, formatting, internationalization

I am trying to format the hour fraction of a date object using Intl.DateTimeFormat. The desired output should only be a number (between 0 and 23).
Code:

```
var myopts = {
   hour: '2-digit',
   hour12 : false
};

var f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de", myopts);

console.log (f.format(new Date()));
```

The output (in Chrome 72  and Firefox 65) is something like "14 Uhr" ("Uhr" is german for "o'clock").

Using locale "en" I could get rid of the appended "am"/"pm" by setting `hour12 : false`.

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/the3ver/dt0k1nLu/)

Comment: If it only has to be a number, why do you have to use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` instead of just `.getHours()` ( which returns the hour as a number between 0 and 23 ) on a date in local time?

Comment: @Shilly well, we are using Intl in this project to produce localized output for dates and numbers. Of course I can put in an ugly if(..) for this case in the code, but I do not want to. Hence the question:-)

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck then! I failed this exercise and switched back to using a formatter function since I could not get INTL to produce the exact string I wanted either.